# Laravel 5 dates

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

i tried checking and set status by range date

```
foreach($reserves as $reserve){


        $table = App\TableDiagram::where('t_number',$reserve->st_number)
            ->first();

        if (App\BusyTable::where('table_diagram_id',$table->id)
            ->where('end','>=',Carbon::now())
            ->first()) {
            $reserve->status = 'active';
        }
        if (App\DepTable::where('table_diagram_id',$table->id)
            ->where('end','>=',Carbon::now())
            ->first()) {
            $reserve->status = 'deposited';
        }
    }
```

many for some reason an active, but don't pass on the condition
what is wrong?

**UPDATE**

added screen what i doing

date format on screen just replaced like `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($reserve->reserve_date)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')`

[image]

Comment: what is your date format of `end` column ? can your provide one example ?

Comment: @Vikash `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: Try my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to format your date.

Try this

```
$formattedDate = date('m-d-Y H:i:s',time());

 if (App\BusyTable::where('table_diagram_id',$table->id)
        ->where('end','>=',$formattedDate)
        ->first()) {
        $reserve->status = 'active';
    }
    if (App\DepTable::where('table_diagram_id',$table->id)
        ->where('end','>=',$formattedDate)
        ->first()) {
        $reserve->status = 'deposited';
    }
```

Comment: No, you not understand, I not compare $active_reserve

Comment: You need to format your date you can also use `Carbon::now()->timestamp` in place of `time()`

Comment: i did you upd answer but not working maybe its magic but I had already tried everything

Comment: Log both of the query and see is it returning something by using Log::info($your_query);  and see. please tell me . i m trying to solve your problem

Comment: Your date format look like `d-m-Y H:i:s` just replace `$formattedDate = date('d-m-Y H:i:s')` and it should work.

Comment: im added screen what i do, i check it

Comment: No, I wrote it just to view, not controller method

Comment: This may be due to date?

Comment: Ya I think there is problem with date format, if same format is not there then it will not compare correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either `->whereDate('end', '>=', Carbon::now());` or `->where(\DB::raw("DATE(end) >= '".Carbon::now()."'"));`

**UPDATE**

I would do like this

```
$table = App\BusyTable::where('table_diagram_id',$table->id)->first();

if (Carbon::now()->lt(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $table->end)) {
            $reserve->status = 'active';
        }
```

Comment: Could you please show how you did? Also please Laravel version and result

Comment: This may be due to date?

Comment: if you'd paste the result of **dd(App\BusyTable::where('table_diagram_id',$table->id)->first());**, I could give more exact answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134410/discussion-between-rai-and-avik-aghajanyan).

Comment: can you go to the chat ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it must work:

```
if (App\BusyTable::where( function ($query) use ($table) {
                         $query->where('table_diagram_id',$table->id)
                            ->where('end','>=',Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                     })->first()) {
    $reserve->status = 'active';
}



if (App\DepTable::where( function ($query) use ($table) {
                     $query->where('table_diagram_id',$table->id)
                        ->where('end','>=',Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                 })->first()) {
    $reserve->status = 'deposited';
}
```

Hope it help you :)